# Use component selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am working on my Angular 4 project. I have two components, one is TaskCardComponent and CalendarComponent. There is a css class in CalendarComponent called 'calendar'. What I want to do is append TaskCardComponent-html to this 'calendar' class div using jquery in CalendarComponent .ts file. I know there is a way to use selector of component. But I have requirement to use jquery only. How can I do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But I have requirement to use jquery only.` who enfoces this? This is definitley somebody who does not know what he / she says. It is strongly recommended **not** to use `jquery` inside angular apps. Use `@ViewChild` for DOM access instead - https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 0):

Go to that component where you want to use jQuery.
declare this variable above the class

```
declare var jQuery:any
```

This jQuery variable is availabe in your component and you can use as you use jQuery in javascript.

```
jQuery("...")
```

One more thing to check before using. you must add jquery reference in Index.html